# karate : How to set the Json value if object name contains period in an array

Tags: json, parameter-passing, karate

Here is my JSON request example code and as u can see #(Paramtervale) as to be replaced by MyValue

```
Below is the example of the request json and code:
            * request 
    """
            {
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "match_data": {
                    "Event.Data.message": "#(Paramtervale)"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "match_data": {
                    "Event.Name": "#(Paramtervale2)"
                  }
                }
              ],
              "filter": {
                "range": {
                  "@timestamp": {
                    "gte": "now-1m"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
            """
* set request.Event.Data.message = myvalue
* set request.{Event.Data.message} = myvalue
* set request.(Event.Data.message) = myvalue
```

None of the above is working, can anyone please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample Code:

```
Feature: Validation

    Scenario:
        * def req =
            """
            {
                "query": {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [
                            {
                                "match_data": {
                                    "Event.Data.message": "#(Paramtervale)"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "match_data": {
                                    "Event.Name": "#(Paramtervale2)"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "filter": {
                            "range": {
                                "@timestamp": {
                                    "gte": "now-1m"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            """
        * req.query.bool.must[0].match_data["Event.Data.message"] = "abc"
        * req.query.bool.must[1].match_data["Event.Name"] = "def"
        * print req
```

Answer (score 4):

Here are 2 different ways, note that for updating a JSON, `set` is not needed any more. When special characters are in key names, use the square-bracket approach to refer to JSON data:

```
* def temp = { 'a.b': 'xxx' }
* temp['a.b'] = 'yyy'
* match temp == { 'a.b': 'yyy' }

# using embedded expressions
* def val = 'yyy'
* def temp = { 'a.b': '#(val)' }
* match temp == { 'a.b': 'yyy' }
```

Comment: * Request['Event.Data.message'] = logDataMessage is working partially. The parameter and value appending the end as "Event.Data.message": "MyValue", so the request is going wrong. The value is replaced in actual and also it's appending the same at the end of the request.

Comment: i am calling/defining the json from the call function. like read('classpath:'query.json')